# php - mysql - application and database updates deploy via tfs

Tags: php, mysql, windows, tfs, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new to tfs. We only have access to the latest free version due to budget constraints. We locked behind firewalls and do not have direct internet access. Every part of the solution needs to be self sufficient. We working on a php application using mysql running on both windows and ubuntu servers. Currently we are deploying manually to 4 servers. Plan is to expand to possibly 100 servers. Installing new servers is easy, but the challenge is with constant updates to code pages and possibly DB changes both in structure and data. We have found limited information about deploying via tfs. We have found a number of technologies like tfs, git with gitlib, jenkins and other, but no basic description of how all of these would work. What is needed and how to do it. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Could you specify how did you deploy manually?

Comment: We user TFS 2018 on site free addition for up to 5 people as we are 3 and have little to no Internet access.

We use Window's WAMP and Ubuntu LAMP stack. Restore site DB via workbench and manually copy files to the www root folder.

Comment: TFS 2018 on site free addition for up to 5 people, do you mean VSTS? https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/

Comment: No, TFS 2018 on site. No internet access and dev team of 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VSTS, [deploy a private build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) is necessary, so that it can access all your servers.

Copying files to the www root folder on your servers is easy to achieve. You can [create a build or release definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1), and add a [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) task in the definition to copy the files to remote machines.

Regarding DB changes, you need to check whether there are command lines, or script or api for workbench to restore the DB of MySQL. In this way, you could add Command Line task or Script task in your build/release definition to restore it.

Comment: As we do not have direct internet access what ever we do needs to be on the internal WAN / LAN. Do you know if there is a video explaining how to do the above advice?

Comment: You could refer to the links I provided, there are lots screenshots to help you start the process.